# Razor Views acting crazy after VS 2015 Enterprise install

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2015

I did a fresh install of Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition. The installation completed without any errors.

Now when I open a solution in Visual Studio 2015, all my Razor views are giving errors:

[image: razor error]

I tried the various suggestions I found through Google. I tried setting MVC `Copy Local` to `True` in **References** for the project. I also tried, closing and opening Visual Studio. Trying different Views and finally un-installing then re-installing MVC 3. Nothing works!

Any ideas? :(

Comment: What worked for me once was by using nuget to uninstall then reinstall the packages, have you tried that?

Comment: Clean and Rebuild your MVC project and your entire solution.

Comment: this is usually an bad version number reference in your `~/web.config` and `~/Views/Web.config`

Comment: Tried both, still no joy :(

Comment: Had it been a version issue, shouldn't my other team members experience this too? None are having the same issue. Though they are on VS 2013 Premium.

Comment: i would just make sure all of the versions in the config files match the version numbers in your References.. if the do, try closing all of your open windows and reopen the views